# How to select the exact element

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have the next jQuery code :

```
$('#example li a').click(function(){
    var className = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.className').show();
});
```

This code suppose to take the NAME of the id of the clicked element, and find the class with the same name and show her.

It isn't working probably because i am trying to go to an element but it is the name  (maybe like a string).

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Thanks,
Robi

Answer (score 5):

You're passing an ordinary string containing the literal `.className`.
It has nothing to do with your variable.

You need to insert the variable into the string:

```
$('.' + className).show();
```

Comment: I edited your post to remove an extra apostrophe that broke the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#example li a').click(function(){
    var className = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.' + className).show();
});
```